# Use (partykit- Nodeapply- Info_node) to extrac information within the function

Tags: function, nodes, decision-tree, extract, party

I am trying to extract information coming from nodeapply( info_node) function.

I want to automate the process so that I can extract the information of a list a node ids and operate on them later.

The example as follow:

```
data("cars", package = "datasets")
ct <- ctree(dist ~ speed, data = cars)

node5 <-nodeapply(as.simpleparty(ct), ids = 5, info_node)
node5$`5`$n
```

I use the code above to extract the number of records on node 5.

I want to create a function to extract the info from a series of node:

```
infonode <- function(x,y){
  for (j in x){
  info = nodeapply(y, j, info_node)
  print(info$`j`$n)
  }
}
```

But the result always comes back as null.

I wonder if the type of "J" is wrong within the function that leads to a null read in the print.

If someone could help me it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give `nodeapply()` a list of `ids` and then not only list with a single element will be extracted but a list of all selected nodes. This is the only `partykit`-specific part of your question.

From that point forward it is simply operating on standard named lists in R, without anything `partykit` specific about that. To address your problem you can easily use `[[` indexing rather than `$` indexing, either with an integer or a character index:

```
node5[[1]]$n
##  n 
## 19 
node5[["5"]]$n
##  n 
## 19
```

Thus, in your `infonode()` function you could replace `info$`j`$n` by either `info[[1]]$n` or `info[[as.character(j)]]$n`.

However, I would simply do this with an `sapply()`:

```
ni <- nodeapply(as.simpleparty(ct), ids = 3:5, info_node)
sapply(ni, "[[", "n")
## 3.n 4.n 5.n 
##  15  16  19
```

Or some variation of this...

Comment: Thank you!  This works so well that I cannot thank you enough for the help!  Really appreciate it!